# Facing certificate issue while access the ecentric payment

Tags: php, curl, payment, client-certificates

I want to integrate the sandbox.ecentric.co.za payment method, as per the documentation we first need to generate the Client Certificate.
I have generated the client certificate from Trustwave(https://certs.securetrust.com/)(vikings cloud) and when I downloaded the zip then zip contains the chain.cer, test.com.p7b, test.com.der, test.com.cer, test.com.pem files. I am trying to generate the pfx file but unable to generate that.

I have tried to directly pass the pem file into the curl but still not getting the response.

`$certificate_location = '/test.com.pem'; curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, $certificate_location);curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, $certificate_location);curl_setopt_array($curl, array(CURLOPT_URL => 'https://sandboxpg.ecentric.co.za/PaymentGateway/V1',CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,CURLOPT_VERBOSE=> 1,CURLOPT_SSLVERSION=>CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2,CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate','Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8','SOAPAction: "AddCard"')));$response = curl_exec($curl);if (curl_errno($curl)) {echo 'cURL error: ' . curl_error($curl);}echo $response;`

This will give the cURL error: OpenSSL SSL_connect: Connection was reset in connection to sandboxpg.ecentric.co.za:443

Anyone have any idea about how to integrate the ecentric with php curl.